# Error fitting a simulation model to data with optim in R

Tags: r, optimization

Good afternoon:
I have 30 years of population data on guanacos, and a matrix simulation model; I want to estimate the optimal values of 12 of the model's parameters in R using optim, by minimizing the residual sums of squares (Sum(obs-pred)^2). I created a function with the model. The model is working fine, for if I invoke the function with fixed parameter values I get the exected results. When I call optim with a sewt of initial parameters and the function, I get the following error message: "the argument a13 is absent, with no value by omission"; 
also: Message of lost warning: In if (SSQ == 0) { :
the condition has a length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Called from: top level  (freely translated from Spanish).

Please find below the R code in three sections: (1) first with the function "guafit" declaration, (2) with a standalone run of the model invoking the "guafit", and (3) the call of "optim" with its starting parameter values.

Thank you, Jorge Rabinovich

```
# Section (1):
# Clean all
    rm(list=ls())

#####################################################################
####################### Function "guafit"  ##########################
#####################################################################

    guafit <- function(SSQ,a13,a21,a32,a33,ad1,ad2,ad3,ad4,bd1,bd2,bd3,bd4) {

# Create the field population (a 30-years time series)
# ====================================================
    tfield <- c(12334,10670,19078,11219,11771,12323,13027,14094,14604,17775,20774,16410,17626,21445,21111,20777,28978,27809,28935,38841,38363,32273,43128,58597,52456,33125,61334,60488,44773,56973)

# Assign values to the vector of the initial population
# =====================================================
    G <- matrix(c(0,0,0),ncol=3, nrow=1)
    G[1]= 1542
    G[2]= 740
    G[3]= 3885

# Load the matrices with their initial values for all 30 time units (years)
# =========================================================================
    if (SSQ == 0) {
    a<-array(0,dim=c(3,3,30))
    for(i in 1:29) {
    a[1,3,i]= a13
    a[2,1,i]= a21
    a[3,2,i]= a32
    a[3,3,i]= a33
            }
        }
# Initialize some  variables
# ==========================
    tmod<-array(1,dim=c(1,30)); tmod <- as.numeric(tmod)
    densprop<-array(1,dim=c(1,30)); densprop <- as.numeric(densprop)
    FdeltaFe<-array(1,dim=c(1,30)); FdeltaFe <- as.numeric(FdeltaFe)
    FdeltaSc<-array(1,dim=c(1,30)); FdeltaSc <- as.numeric(FdeltaSc)
    FdeltaSj<-array(1,dim=c(1,30)); FdeltaSj <- as.numeric(FdeltaSj)
    FdeltaSa<-array(1,dim=c(1,30)); FdeltaSa <- as.numeric(FdeltaSa)

# N0 is the initial population vector
# It is multiplied by 2 to represewnt both sexes
# ===============================================
# Transfer guanacos (G) as a vector with the three age classes
    N0 <- G
    tmod[1] <- (N0[1]+N0[2]+N0[3]) * 2

# Declaration of the initial simulation conditions
# ================================================
# ng is the number of female individuals per age class (dim 3x30)
# tmod is the total (both sexes) population (sum of the three age classes * 2)
    ng <- matrix( 0, nrow= 3, ncol=30)
    ng[,1] <- N0

# We assume a constant carrying capacity (K= 60000 individuals)
    carcap= 60000

# Start simulation for 30 years
    for(i in 1:29) {
#Set up the density-dependent coefficients

    densprop[i] <- tmod[i] / carcap

# Calculate the density-dependent factors
    FdeltaFe[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad1)*bd1))
    FdeltaSc[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad2)*bd2))
    FdeltaSj[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad3)*bd3))
    FdeltaSa[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad4)*bd4))

# Apply the density-dependent factors to each coefficient in its own age class

    a[1,3,i]= a[1,3,i] * FdeltaFe[i]
    a[2,1,i]= a[2,1,i] * FdeltaSc[i]
    a[3,2,i]= a[3,2,i] * FdeltaSj[i]
    a[3,3,i]= a[3,3,i] * FdeltaSa[i]

# Project the total population with the matrix operation

    ng[,i+1] <- a[,,i]%*%ng[,i]
    tmod[i+1] <- (ng[1,i+1] + ng[2,i+1] + ng[3,i+1]) * 2

# End of the 30-years simulation loop
            }

# Calculate the residual sum of squares (SSQ)       
            SSQ = sum((tmod - tfield)^2)
               return(list(outm=tmod, outc=tfield, elSSQ=SSQ, matrices=a,     losgua=G, losguaxe=ng))

# End of function guafit
        }
#################################################################################

# Section (2):

# Initialize conditions and parameters before calling function guafit

    SSQ <- 0

# Initialize the 8 density-dependent coefficients (2 coefficients per age class)
# ==============================================================================
    ad1= 1.195680167
    ad2= 1.127219245
    ad3= 1.113739384
    ad4= 1.320456815
    bd1= 10.21559509
    bd2= 9.80201883
    bd3= 9.760834107
    bd4= 10.59390027

# Assign initial values to the transition matrix coefficients
# ============================================================
    a21= 0.6
    a32=0.8
    a33=0.9
    a13=0.37

# Initialization of conditions is finished, we can  call function guafit
# As a test, we call function guafit only once to check for results
    myresults <- guafit(SSQ,a13,a21,a32,a33,ad1, ad2, ad3, ad4, bd1, bd2, bd3, bd4)
# We save the results of interest of function guafit with new variables 
    restmod <- myresults$outm
    tfield <- myresults$outc
    SSQvalue <- myresults$elSSQ
    lasmatrices <- myresults$matrices
    reslosgua <- myresults$losgua
    reslosguaxe <- myresults$losguaxe
    SSQvalue
# Graph the results
    axisx <- c(1982:2011)
    plot(axisx,tfield)
    lines(axisx,restmod)

#################################################################################

# Section (3):

# I try the optim function 

# First creating the initial parameter values variable to pass as an argument

    startparam <- c(SSQ, a13,a21,a32,a33,ad1, ad2, ad3, ad4, bd1, bd2, bd3, bd4)
    optim(startparam, guafit)
# and I got error message mentioned above.

# I also tried calling as:
    optim(par=startparam, fn=guafit) 
# and I got the same error message

# I also tried calling optim but passing the values directly as a list of values:
    startparam <- c(SSQ=0, a13=0.37, a21=0.6, a32=0.8, a33=0.9, ad1=1.1, ad2=1.1, ad3=1.1, ad4=1.1, bd1=10, bd2=10, bd3=10, bd4=10)
    optim(startparam, guafit)
    optim(par=startparam, fn=guafit) 

# and I got the same error message
```

Comment: Could you initialize stuff outside of the function?  I am just guessing.  That might be the first thing I would try.  Although, I have only looked at the code for a few moments.

Comment: `a13` appears to be a constant, but it looks like you are trying to estimate it.  Maybe remove your constants from your `optim` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I got the code running, but I am not sure whether it returns the correct parameter estimates.  I tried two different approaches.

With the first approach I did the following:

1. placed all data and initializations outside the function.
2. removed constants from the `optim` statement
3. assumed `ad1`, `ad2`, `ad3` and `ad4` were constants and not parameters to be estimated.  I guess you could say I assumed `ad1`, `ad2`, `ad3` and `ad4` were constant offsets.

This first approach returned estimates of `bd1`, `bd2`, `bd3` and `bd4` that closely matched your initial values.

With the second approach I did the following:

1. placed all data and initializations outside the function.
2. removed constants from the `optim` statement
3. assumed `ad1`, `ad2`, `ad3` and `ad4` were parameters to be estimated.

This second approach returned estimates of all eight parameters: `ad1`, `ad2`, `ad3`, `ad4`, `bd1`, `bd2`, `bd3` and `bd4` but I do not think the estimates are correct.  Note that two columns in the Hessian are all `0`.  The SE could not be estimated with this second approach and the estimates of `bd1`, `bd2`, `bd3` and `bd4` were not close to their initial values.

The `R` code for both approaches is below.  Check the code to see whether either approach is doing what you want.  If treating `ad1`, `ad2`, `ad3`, and `ad4` as parameters is critical then perhaps the model code will have to be revised.

Here is the `R` code and output for the first approach:

```
set.seed(2345)

guafit <- function(param) {

          bd1 <- param[1]
          bd2 <- param[2]
          bd3 <- param[3]
          bd4 <- param[4]

# Start simulation for 30 years
    for(i in 1:29) {

# Set up the density-dependent coefficients
    densprop[i] <- tmod[i] / carcap

# Calculate the density-dependent factors
    FdeltaFe[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad1)*bd1))
    FdeltaSc[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad2)*bd2))
    FdeltaSj[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad3)*bd3))
    FdeltaSa[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad4)*bd4))

# Apply density-dependent factors to each coefficient in its own age class
    a[1,3,i]= a[1,3,i] * FdeltaFe[i]
    a[2,1,i]= a[2,1,i] * FdeltaSc[i]
    a[3,2,i]= a[3,2,i] * FdeltaSj[i]
    a[3,3,i]= a[3,3,i] * FdeltaSa[i]

# Project the total population with the matrix operation
    ng[,i+1]  <- a[,,i]%*%ng[,i]
    tmod[i+1] <- (ng[1,i+1] + ng[2,i+1] + ng[3,i+1]) * 2

# End of the 30-years simulation loop
            }

# Calculate the residual sum of squares (SSQ)       
            SSQ = sum((tmod - tfield)^2)

# End of function guafit
        }

# Create the field population (a 30-years time series)
# ====================================================
    tfield <- c(12334,10670,19078,11219,11771,12323,13027,14094,14604,17775,
                20774,16410,17626,21445,21111,20777,28978,27809,28935,38841,
                38363,32273,43128,58597,52456,33125,61334,60488,44773,56973)

# Initialize conditions and parameters before calling function guafit
    SSQ <- 0

# Assign initial values to the transition matrix coefficients
# ============================================================
    a21 = 0.6
    a32 = 0.8
    a33 = 0.9
    a13 = 0.37

# Assign values to the vector of the initial population
# =====================================================
    G <- matrix(c(0,0,0),ncol=3, nrow=1)
    G[1] = 1542
    G[2] = 740
    G[3] = 3885

# Load the matrices with their initial values for all 30 time units (years)
# =========================================================================

    a <- array(0,dim=c(3,3,30))

    for(i in 1:29) {
    a[1,3,i]= a13
    a[2,1,i]= a21
    a[3,2,i]= a32
    a[3,3,i]= a33
            }

# Initialize some  variables
# ==========================
    tmod<-array(1,dim=c(1,30)); tmod <- as.numeric(tmod)

    densprop <- array(1,dim=c(1,30)) 
    densprop <- as.numeric(densprop)

    FdeltaFe <- array(1,dim=c(1,30)) 
    FdeltaFe <- as.numeric(FdeltaFe)

    FdeltaSc <- array(1,dim=c(1,30))
    FdeltaSc <- as.numeric(FdeltaSc)

    FdeltaSj <- array(1,dim=c(1,30))
    FdeltaSj <- as.numeric(FdeltaSj)

    FdeltaSa <- array(1,dim=c(1,30))
    FdeltaSa <- as.numeric(FdeltaSa)

    ng <- matrix( 0, nrow= 3, ncol=30)

# We assume a constant carrying capacity (K= 60000 individuals)
    carcap= 60000

# N0 is the initial population vector
# It is multiplied by 2 to represewnt both sexes
# ===============================================
# Transfer guanacos (G) as a vector with the three age classes

    N0 <- G

    tmod[1] <- (N0[1]+N0[2]+N0[3]) * 2

# Declaration of the initial simulation conditions
# ================================================
# ng is the number of female individuals per age class (dim 3x30)
# tmod is total (both sexes) population (sum of the three age classes * 2)

    ng[,1] <- N0


ad1 <- 1.195680167
ad2 <- 1.127219245
ad3 <- 1.113739384
ad4 <- 1.320456815

 fit <- optim ( c(10.21559509,
                   9.80201883,
                   9.760834107,
                  10.59390027), fn=guafit, method='BFGS', hessian=TRUE)
 fit
```

Here is the output for the first approach:

```
$par
[1] 11.315899 11.886347 11.912239  9.675885

$value
[1] 1177381086

$counts
function gradient 
     150       17 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

$hessian
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 417100.8  306371.2  326483.2  941186.8
[2,] 306371.2  516636.4  370602.5 1061540.5
[3,] 326483.2  370602.5  577929.7 1135695.9
[4,] 941186.8 1061540.5 1135695.9 3720506.4
```

Here are the four parameter estimates and their standard errors:

```
           mle          se
[1,] 11.315899 0.002439888
[2,] 11.886347 0.002240669
[3,] 11.912239 0.002153876
[4,]  9.675885 0.001042035
```

Here is the `R` code for the second approaches, that estimates eight parameters.  The SE could not be estimated with this second approach:

```
set.seed(2345)

guafit <- function(param) {

          ad1 <- param[1]
          ad2 <- param[2]
          ad3 <- param[3]
          ad4 <- param[4]
          bd1 <- param[5]
          bd2 <- param[6]
          bd3 <- param[7]
          bd4 <- param[8]

# Start simulation for 30 years
    for(i in 1:29) {

# Set up the density-dependent coefficients
    densprop[i] <- tmod[i] / carcap

# Calculate the density-dependent factors
    FdeltaFe[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad1)*bd1))
    FdeltaSc[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad2)*bd2))
    FdeltaSj[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad3)*bd3))
    FdeltaSa[i]= 1/(1+exp((densprop[i]-ad4)*bd4))

# Apply the density-dependent factors to each coefficient in its own age class
    a[1,3,i]= a[1,3,i] * FdeltaFe[i]
    a[2,1,i]= a[2,1,i] * FdeltaSc[i]
    a[3,2,i]= a[3,2,i] * FdeltaSj[i]
    a[3,3,i]= a[3,3,i] * FdeltaSa[i]

# Project the total population with the matrix operation

    ng[,i+1]  <- a[,,i]%*%ng[,i]
    tmod[i+1] <- (ng[1,i+1] + ng[2,i+1] + ng[3,i+1]) * 2

# End of the 30-years simulation loop
            }

# Calculate the residual sum of squares (SSQ)       
            SSQ = sum((tmod - tfield)^2)

# End of function guafit
        }

# Create the field population (a 30-years time series)
# ====================================================
    tfield <- c(12334,10670,19078,11219,11771,12323,13027,14094,14604,17775,
                20774,16410,17626,21445,21111,20777,28978,27809,28935,38841,
                38363,32273,43128,58597,52456,33125,61334,60488,44773,56973)

# Initialize conditions and parameters before calling function guafit
    SSQ <- 0

# Assign initial values to the transition matrix coefficients
# ============================================================
    a21 = 0.6
    a32 = 0.8
    a33 = 0.9
    a13 = 0.37

# Assign values to the vector of the initial population
# =====================================================
    G <- matrix(c(0,0,0),ncol=3, nrow=1)
    G[1] = 1542
    G[2] = 740
    G[3] = 3885

# Load the matrices with their initial values for all 30 time units (years)
# =========================================================================

    a <- array(0,dim=c(3,3,30))

    for(i in 1:29) {
    a[1,3,i]= a13
    a[2,1,i]= a21
    a[3,2,i]= a32
    a[3,3,i]= a33
            }

# Initialize some  variables
# ==========================
    tmod<-array(1,dim=c(1,30)); tmod <- as.numeric(tmod)

    densprop <- array(1,dim=c(1,30)) 
    densprop <- as.numeric(densprop)

    FdeltaFe <- array(1,dim=c(1,30)) 
    FdeltaFe <- as.numeric(FdeltaFe)

    FdeltaSc <- array(1,dim=c(1,30))
    FdeltaSc <- as.numeric(FdeltaSc)

    FdeltaSj <- array(1,dim=c(1,30))
    FdeltaSj <- as.numeric(FdeltaSj)

    FdeltaSa <- array(1,dim=c(1,30))
    FdeltaSa <- as.numeric(FdeltaSa)

    ng <- matrix( 0, nrow= 3, ncol=30)

# We assume a constant carrying capacity (K= 60000 individuals)
    carcap= 60000

# N0 is the initial population vector
# It is multiplied by 2 to represewnt both sexes
# ===============================================
# Transfer guanacos (G) as a vector with the three age classes

    N0 <- G

    tmod[1] <- (N0[1]+N0[2]+N0[3]) * 2

# Declaration of the initial simulation conditions
# ================================================
# ng is the number of female individuals per age class (dim 3x30)
# tmod is the total (both sexes) population (sum of the three age classes * 2)

    ng[,1] <- N0

 fit <- optim ( c( 1.195680167,
                   1.127219245,
                   1.113739384,
                   1.320456815,
                  10.21559509,
                   9.80201883,
                   9.760834107,
                  10.59390027), fn=guafit, method='BFGS', hessian=TRUE)

 fit
```

Here is the output for the second approach:

```
$par
[1]   0.9191288   1.0266562   1.1754382   0.9973042 248.5229404  75.2993413 380.2445394 460.2091730

$value
[1] 1031918725

$counts
function gradient 
     705       76 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

$hessian
             [,1]          [,2] [,3]        [,4]          [,5]          [,6] [,7]        [,8]
[1,] 7.688038e+09  4.293539e+07    0  2.89082527  6.248865e+04  4.860839e+04    0  0.02980232
[2,] 4.293539e+07  2.761336e+06    0  0.29802322 -3.247231e+03  1.245818e+04    0 -0.02980232
[3,] 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00    0  0.00000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00    0  0.00000000
[4,] 2.890825e+00  2.980232e-01    0 55.25350571 -2.980232e-02  0.000000e+00    0  0.02980232
[5,] 6.248865e+04 -3.247231e+03    0 -0.02980232  8.401275e+01 -3.635883e+00    0 -0.02980232
[6,] 4.860839e+04  1.245818e+04    0  0.00000000 -3.635883e+00  3.185868e+01    0 -0.02980232
[7,] 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00    0  0.00000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00    0  0.00000000
[8,] 2.980232e-02 -2.980232e-02    0  0.02980232 -2.980232e-02 -2.980232e-02    0  0.02980232
```

Answer (score 0):

Monday, April 27, 2015

Dear Mark:

Thanks a million for the work and ideas you put into my problem.

A few comments and additions:

(1) All the 8 parameters ad1, ad2, ad3, ad4, bd1, bd2, bd3, and bd4 have to be estimated (as you have done in your 2nd approach).

(2) But additionally the 30-period 3x3 matrix [ a(3x3x30) ] has four elements (a13, a21, a32, and a33) that **also** have to be estimated by optim.

(3) That is the reason why I had the matrix a[,,i] passed as a parameter; maybe when you deleted a[,,i] as an argument calling optim, the problem disappeared.

(4) Maybe here is where my original problem started; I remember having read somewhere that optim has problems with parameters that have dimensions; do you think my error message had something to do with having a[,,i] as an argument in the parameter list?

(5) I know I am a little bit ambitious: I am requesting optim to minimize my SSQ (residual sum of squares between field and population vectors) changing a total of 128 parameters (4x30= 120 for the a[,,i] matrix, and the eight additional parameters mentioned in (1).

(6) if the problem resulted from having a[,,i] as an argument in the parameter list, do you think it would disappear if I replace the matrix a[,,i] in the list of arguments when calling optim by a list of 120 individual values?

(7) Another important question: I need the model population vector (tmod) as an output variable from optim after fitting is finished; I inserted to your scripot (approach #1) the command "return(restmod= tmod)" just before the calculation of the SSQ, and I get an error message saying that "objective function in optim evaluates that the size 30 is not 1". Have I made a mistake when requesting this output?

(8) And finally, a further VERY important question: I forgot to mention that my parameters have to be constraint; they are very simple: all non-zero coefficients of the a[,,i] matrix (i.e., a[1,3,i]= a13, a[2,1,i]= a21, a[3,2,i]= a32, a[3,3,i]= a33) have to be <=1, except a13 that has to be <=0.5 (the other 8 parameters are not constrained). How do you pass to optim the necessary constraints?

Again, many thanks,

Jorge

Comment: Hi Jorge.  I have not studied your model yet, just the syntax of the R function.  Maybe I can study the model this weekend.  The model is very intriguing and I am interested in estimating parameters in matrix population models.  So additional study of your model on my part would be time well spent.  However, I might not be able to get it to work.

Comment: City Bell, Tuesday, April 28, 2015, 10:12

Comment: Hi Mark: Thank you very much for your interest and excellent disposition to help me on this matter. I would be very glad to send you a general scheme of the model we are using, and the reasons for this fitting of the time series data of a wildlife population (we are trying a novel approach to detect density-dependence in population regulation). If you can provide me with an e-mail I could send you a document with a summary of that approach. Otherwise (if you prefer anonimity, which is very understandable) I will investigate if I can send you an attachment via Stackoverflow. Thanks, Jorge

Comment: Jorge, here is an email mark.wayne.miller@gmail.com  I cannot promise I can get the model to work, but I can try to look at it this weekend.